# Add SQL string into EF Core LINQ ( append ZQL query)

Tags: postgresql, linq, asp.net-core

I have the `ASP.Core .Net 5.0` app. I work with `PostgreSQL` with using of `Entity Framework Core`. Query to database do with `LINQ`. How can I add part of raw `SQL` string to `LINQ` query?
For example:

```
var result = Customers.Where(x => x.Age >= 18).Where("==> 'Vasya, Ilya'");
```

where `Customers` is `repository`.

This is necessary because I want to use full text search with `ZomboDb`.

Comment: @EricB.Ridge help if you can please

Comment: Not with pure EF Core. But possible with third party extensions.

Comment: Are you looking for [`FromSqlRaw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)?

Comment: You should be able to do `var result = Customers.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Name ==> 'Vasya, Ilya'").Where(x => x.Age >= 18);`